# Android Marketplace Updates & Eclipse Projects

Tags: android, eclipse, version-control, google-play, updates

So I have managed to get a couple apps up on the marketplace only to have a stray thought of what is the best way to go about managing my projects/apps within eclipse to accommodate future updates to the marketplace. My question resides within Eclipse and what to do with my projects/apps as I apply updates.

Do I simply copy my project/app, paste it and the increment the version information accordingly?  Or am I continuously working on my published project/app?  Or...Is there a recommended/preferred method of going about this.  Since they are up and good on the marketplace I am leery of doing something that will cause problems for me later on down the line.

And don't change the package name....correct?

This is what I currently have on the Marketplace...

[Wind Chill Calculator](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.nmedu.windchill&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm9yZy5ubWVkdS53aW5kY2hpbGwiXQ..)

[True Love Game](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.frostysmooth.truelove)

First of all, everyone's posts were very helpful and I have spent some time looking over documentation through the links provided.

So...and brace for impact as I say this.  Being one who has NEVER used any form of SCM for my projects this is all new to me (as everyone's faces cringe), which is why I am asking the original question in the first place.  I hate to say tell me anything without doing my research...so within the past few hours using git within eclipse I have gleamed the following:
Team > Share Project ...ignores...any tags(for version info)which is what I am after...commits...THEN

Clone?  File -> Import -> Git -> Git Repository  at this point once I have cloned my project do I create a new tag with the new version info, and go through the commit process again?  If this is the case I now have two items in my Git Repository.  One of which has the single tag of 1.0, and the other item which contains two tags 1.0 and 1.1, and when I look at the history I see two tags Version 1.0 and Version 1.1. Then I just switch between the resources I need from within the repository?

I just want to make sure my process is correct before I begin to implement some of this on existing projects that are pretty extensive already.  As for the rest I am just going to learn on the fly...branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, dont change the package name, that will make it new app, instead of upgrade of original.

Use a version control system, like [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/%5d).

Manage Tags for a complete working state of code(through svn), so you can always revert back to that tag.

When ready for new release, increment version no. etc and update on market...

EDIT After addition in question:
Don't get much confused with various GIT/SVN working.. There main purpose is that they will allow you to switch your code back and forth to any point in past, that allows you to code in a way properly knowing that you can always revert back to a Working state.. and it is definitely of much more benefit in a Team , when multiple people are working on same codebase and possibly same files...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a revision control system like SVN or git or one of dozens of other options, and continuously update the single project in Eclipse.  The benefit of using source control is that you can branch into a new project for major changes, update your existing code for minor changes, and tag the branches so you can revert back to an old snapshot in the future.

I personally use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) which is hosted remotely and is free.  It supports SVN and Mercurial.

Comment: Or git, with github. Eclipse has Egit plugin to make that even easier.

Comment: Used everything from RCS to Clearcase to git.  Mercurial is my muse atm.

Answer (score 1):

Being a long-time user of SVN, I recommend subclipse (svn for eclipse).  When you're ready to release another version of your app, create a 'tag' for the release version and you'll always be able to go back to that exact version.

SVN has excellent docs.  There is also TortoiseSVN for repo work outside of eclipse.